# Vertically oriented "row names" for subfigures

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

How can I create vertically oriented "row names" for subfigures? I tried to visualize my idea here:

[image: This is the result I would like to achieve.]

Here is the code for the images using the subcaption package to get subfigures within a larger figure environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \caption{Illustration of various images}
  \label{fig7} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

1. Using a `tabular*` of width equal to `\textwidth` and `m{<length>}` columns.
2. Using the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package.
3. Boxing one of the images to measure its height (this assumes all four images have the same height).

In all three cases the labels are placed inside a `\rotatebox`. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=35cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\pagestyle{empty}

% Measure the image height
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\newlength\ImageHt
\setlength\ImageHt{\ht\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    @{}m{0.5cm}
    @{}m{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.25cm\relax}
    @{}m{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.25cm\relax}
    @{}}
  \rotatebox{90}{row number 1}
  & \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
      \end{subfigure}  
  & \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
      \end{subfigure} \\
  \rotatebox{90}{row number 2} 
  & \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
    \end{subfigure}
  & \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
      \end{subfigure}
  \end{tabular*} 
  \caption{Illustration of various images}
  \label{fig7} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makebox[\ImageHt]{row number 1}}% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
  \end{subfigure}\par\bigskip
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makebox[\ImageHt]{row number 2}}% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \caption{Illustration of various images}
  \label{fig8} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!b]
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makebox[\ImageHt]{row number 1}}% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
  \end{subfigure}\par\bigskip
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makebox[\ImageHt]{row number 2}}% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \caption{Illustration of various images}
  \label{fig8} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]